# App showing Unfortunately, (appname) stopped. up to 3 times after closing the application

Tags: android, sockets, service

I am a beginner trying to learn about `service` in android.... When i run the following code, it is working correctly when the app is Active. But after closing the app from recent app list, its showing dialog "Unfortunately, (appname) stopped." up to 3 times and then stops. But when i am not calling `create_socket()` its working correctly as expected showing `log` of value `i`..... Please help.

```
package com.example.runwaylabz.canvi;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


import xdroid.toaster.Toaster;

public class SocketConnection extends Service {
    private static Socket socket;
    private static InputStream inputStream;
    private static OutputStream outputStream;
    private static String ip;
    private static int port;
    private static SocketConnection socketConnection = null;

public SocketConnection() {
    super();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int i = 1;
                    while (i > 0) {

                        Log.i("HI", "" + i);
                        i++;

                    }
                }
            }).start();


            create_socket();



            return null;
        }
    };
    asyncTask.execute();



    return START_STICKY;
}

private static class instancehelper {
    private static final SocketConnection Instance = new SocketConnection();
}

public static SocketConnection getInstance(String ip, int port) {

    socketConnection = instancehelper.Instance;
    socketConnection.setIp(ip);
    socketConnection.setPort(port);

    return socketConnection;

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public void create_socket() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(ip, port);
                if(socket.isConnected()){
                    Log.w("debug","socket created");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}


public void close_socket(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
                inputStream=null;

            if(inputStream==null){
                Log.w("debug","inputStream Closed");
            }
            else {
                Log.w("debug","inputStreaam not Closed");
            }

            while(inputStream==null){
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
            }


                IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
                outputStream=null;

            if(outputStream==null){
                Log.w("debug","outputStream Closed");
            }
            else {
                Log.w("debug","outputStreaam not Closed");
            }

            while(outputStream==null){
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
            }

            try {
                socket.close();
                socket=null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if(!socket.isClosed()){
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                        socket=null;
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(socket==null){
                Log.w("debug","Socket Closed");
            }
            else {
                Log.w("debug","Socket not Closed");
            }

        }
    }).start();






}

public static void writeouputstream(final String outputstreamString) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                IOUtils.write(("12345678" + outputstreamString).getBytes("ASCII"), outputStream);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}


public void setPort(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public void setIp(String ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
}

public static void setSocket(Socket socket) {
    SocketConnection.socket = socket;
}

public static void setOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream) {
    SocketConnection.outputStream = outputStream;
}

public static void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    SocketConnection.inputStream = inputStream;
}

public static InputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}

public int getPort() {
    return port;
}

public static OutputStream getOutputStream() {
    return outputStream;
}

public static Socket getSocket() {
    return socket;
}

public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

    close_socket();

    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), getInstance(ip,port).getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +1000, restartServicePI);
}
}
```

And the logcat after closing the application is

```
39 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 0) after 90000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
08-01 20:21:32.839 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:267)
08-01 20:21:32.839 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:191)
08-01 20:21:32.839 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:127)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:188)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:168)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:609)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:137)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:187)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:159)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at com.example.runwaylabz.canvi.SocketConnection$2.run(SocketConnection.java:105)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:252)
08-01 20:21:32.840 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi W/System.err:   ... 10 more
08-01 20:21:32.841 26530-26558/com.example.runwaylabz.canvi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-29548
                                                                          Process: com.example.runwaylabz.canvi, PID: 26530
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.InputStream java.net.Socket.getInputStream()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.runwaylabz.canvi.SocketConnection$2.run(SocketConnection.java:115)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Provide a logcat message please

Comment: @oleg  check now and please help

Comment: You have both a NullPointerException and `failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 0)`  which makes me think you are trying to connect to a socket on your local Android device?

Comment: yeah.... i want to reconnect to the socket when the service is restarting.